# how to use TinyMCE visual_anchor_class

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

Using TinyMCE, I want to be able to add a custom class to *some* of the anchor tags in my editor. I found **visual_anchor_class** which I can't get to work. I've created a class called .anchorBtn and added contextmenu to my init.

When I right-click over my anchor (where it says "DONATE"), I see an empty white box.

[image]

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: selector,
  menubar: false,
  height: 300,
  plugins: [
            "link anchor lists code paste image contextmenu"
  ],        
  statusbar: false,
  toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline | bullist numlist | buttons link image | code',                     
  content_css : "css/tinyMCE.css",
  link_list:"cgi/linkList.exe?token="+tkn,
    force_br_newlines : false,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    forced_root_block : '', 
    body_class: "mceBackColor",
    oninit : "setPlainText("+selector+")",
    visual_anchor_class: 'anchorBtn',
    contextmenu: "anchorBtn",
    paste_as_text: true,                
    file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {       

            var tkn=getToken();
            $("#PDFuform").attr("action", "cgi/pdfUpload.exe");
            $("#pdfToken").val(tkn);                                            
                $("#pdfField").val(field_name);
            $('#PDFuform input').click();                        

        },                  
    setup: function (editor) {
      editor.addButton('buttons', {
          type: 'menubutton',
          text: 'Custom Buttons',
          icon: false,
          menu: [
            {
                image : '../img/tourBtn.jpg',
                    title : "SCHEDULE A TOUR",
                    text: "SCHEDULE A TOUR",
                    icon: false,
                    onclick: function () {
                        editor.insertContent("<div class='bbtn bSAT'>SCHEDULE A TOUR</div>");
                    }   
                }
                  ]
      })
    }                                                                       
});
```

What am I doing wrong?